# Нужна ли запятая в этом случае перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Я видел это все неоднократно и на разных публиках и на очень апофеозных.*

Правильно ли понимаю, что здесь не надо ставить запятые перед союзом "и", потому что тут только однородные члены - "на разных публиках и апофеозных"? То есть предложение можно сделать: "Я видел на разных публиках и апофеозных".
Или тут вступает другое правило, что повторение союза "и" второй раз и нужна запятая?

Comment: Можно ещё и двоеточием паузу отбить перед двумя И.

Answer (score 1):

*Я видел это все неоднократно **и на рАзных публиках,  и на очень апофеОзных*** (публиках).

Обстоятельства (как часто? в каких случаях?) неоднородны, но второе обстоятельство — это однородный ряд с повторяющимся союзом И... И.